# I don't see any chi2 in the python stats printout

Tags: python

The python code below is not showing the chi2 and reduced chi2. It only shows variables and correlations. Why is this?

The code is shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#<examples/doc_model1.py>
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp, linspace, loadtxt
from lmfit import  Model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = loadtxt('model1d_gauss.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"
    return (amp/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid)) * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*wid**2))

gmodel = Model(gaussian)
result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=5, wid=1)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
#<end examples/doc_model1.py>
```

The output is below

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gaussian)
[[Variables]]
    amp:   8.88021829 +/- 0.113594 (1.28%) (init= 5)
    cen:   5.65866102 +/- 0.010304 (0.18%) (init= 5)
    wid:   0.69765468 +/- 0.010304 (1.48%) (init= 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(amp, wid)                  =  0.577
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry, this is fixed in the master branch of the git repository.

You can get at and print out values for any of the attributes of the Model result (see  https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#modelresult-attributes ), but they are not correctly printed as part of the fit report in version 0.9.6.  Again, fixed in the master repo.